# Correct method to write Unit test cases in Node JS which follows MVC architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, typescript

Consider the following example :

a.js

```
import B from "b";
export default class A {
    classAMethod() {
       //do something
       let b = new B();
       b.classBMethod();
    }
}
```

b.js

```
import C from "c";
 export default class B {
    classBMethod() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //do Something
        let c = new C();
        c.classCMethod().then((result) => {
           let computedResult = // do something with the result
           resolve(computedResult);
        }).catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        })
      });
    }
 }
```

c.js

```
import * as redis from "redis";
import {Promise} from "bluebird";
let client = client.createClient();
Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

export default class C {
  classCMethod() {
     return client.getAsyc("someKey");
  }
}
```

Here is my question now :

While I am writing the unit test case for `classAMethod()` should I need to stub `classBMethod()` or should the test case go through `classBMethod()` and stub `redis' s createClient method`, as b module is importing c module which in turn requires redis client to be created?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but **stubbing redis' s createClient method** probably means Integration Testing not Unit Testing ? So if you want unit testing maybe stubbing B is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your view @okoch, I am doing the same, I.e., in unit test of `classAMethod()` I am stubbing `classBMethod()`. However, when I run my test cases using mocha, it does not run through completion, after successfully running all test cases it hangs due to `redis.createClient()`, which establishes connection to redis. Not very clear why this might be happening.